# Retrieve clicked widget name in Tcl\Tk

Tags: events, tcl, bind, tk-toolkit

I have a very big Tcl/Tk application with a lot of widget. In order to allow easy access to modify widgets configurations without having to type it in the console per widget/configuration parameter I want to build a dialog for that.
To do so I need an option to easily select the widget to be configured.
I thought to write a function which lets the user to click any widget in the application (any dialog) and retrieves the widget path.
Any ides?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a global-coordinate (e.g., from a `<Button-1>` binding's `%X` and `%Y`) to a widget name using [`winfo containing`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/winfo.htm#M11):

```
bind . <Button-1> {
    set w [winfo containing %X %Y]
    puts "You clicked on $w"
}
```

Be aware that this can interact quite significantly with other bindings! You may need to investigate using a `grab` (carefully; global grabs can cause trouble!) and configuring the `-cursor` in order to tell users what is going on. It's quite do-able, but some thought may be necessary to make it work the way you want.

(Did you know that `winfo containing` is a scripted interface to the functionality at the core of most drag-and-drop handling? It uses exactly the system for mapping positions to windows…)

Comment: Thanks Donal for this detailed explanation. Actually, I was aware of the `winfo containing` statement but you pinpointed exactly my problem - the interaction with another binding...

Comment: Actually, I now tried to use `bind all <1> {set w [winfo contaning %X %Y]; puts $w}`. According to the `bind` manual if several bindings were found to the same widget, there are priorities and the `all` is performed last. Am I missing something?

Comment: Obviously the problem is that the original binding is executed... Can you please help how the `grab` can be utilized to implement it?